# How to share state between instances of the same microservice

Tags: architecture, microservices

I'm rewriting a legacy service, which stores data e.g. counters and uses it for state machine decisions. 
the service receives a query with some key ,looks for its value, update it and perform action if needed.

The new service should be deployed at k8s, where multiple pods of the same service can run, each of the instances can receive a query that could cause a counter to be updated.

How can I sync a counter/data between the replicas and promise consistency ?

Comment: Can't you just use a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an atomic CAS (compare and swap) operation. If the storage is a shared storage as in RDBMS, you can do it using a row level lock. In other words, if your microservice instances are accessing a common RDBMS, you'd be able to do it using a row-level lock.

If your storage is replicated and distributed and the client or the microservice can connect to any node or replica and write on it as in Cassandra, you need a consensus algorithm implementation that will allow the system as a whole agree on which client holds a lock and then do the update. In Cassandra specifically, you can use light weight transaction which implements Paxos and exposes it as a CAS.

If you're not using any of the above databases you can use any other consensus systems like ZooKeeper (ZAB), etcd (Raft) etc.

Apache Curator is a high-level library on top of ZooKeeper. You may refer to this recepe: https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/distributed-atomic-long.html